# Unity3d Smoothly Rotate an object based on a list of Pitch, Roll and Yaw angles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to smoothly rotate an object(a plane) based on a list of angles (Pitch, Roll and Yaw) I get from an API call. The reponse object is the **Rootresponse** below

```
public class ResponseData
{
    public List<int> x; //roll
    public List<int> y; //yaw
    public List<int> z; //pitch
}

public class RootResponse
{
    public ResponseData data;
    public string status; //status of the api call
}
```

I've tried to loop through the values each frame in the **FixedUpdate** method using a while loop using the below piece of code. This throws an **"ArgumentOutOfRange"** exception.

If I use transform.Roatate or Quarternion angle as per the documentation I'm only able to get the final position.

What is the best approach I can opt for in this case?

```
void FixedUpdate(){
    if(shouldUpdate) { //set to true for a success response from the api call
        while(ind < dataLen) {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(new Vector3(batData.x[ind], batData.y[ind], batData.z[ind]), new Vector3(batData.x[ind+1], batData.y[ind + 1], batData.z[ind + 1]), speed * Time.deltaTime);
            ind++; //to increment the index every frame
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (probably) don't want to apply all of the rotations inside the span of one frame regardless of rotational speed.

Rather, you should keep track of how much you are rotating during the course of working through the queue that frame, and get out of the while loop if you meet that.

```
public float maxAngleRotatePerFrame = 5f;

void FixedUpdate(){
    if(shouldUpdate) { //set to true for a success response from the api call
        // Keep track of how far we've traveled in this frame.
        float angleTraveledThisFrame = 0f;

        // Rotate until we've rotated as much as we can in a single frame, 
        // or we run out of rotations to do.
        while (angleTraveledThisFrame < maxAngleRotatePerFrame && ind < dataLen) {
            // Figure out how we want to rotate and how much that is
            Quaternion curRot = transform.rotation;
            Quaternion goalRot = Quaternion.Euler(
                    batData.x[ind],
                    batData.y[ind],
                    batData.z[ind]
                    );
            float angleLeftInThisInd =  Quaternion.Angle(curRot, goalRot);

            // Rotate as much as we can toward that rotation this frame
            float curAngleRotate = Mathf.Min(
                    angleLeftInThisInd, 
                    maxAngleRotatePerFrame - angleTraveledThisFrame
                    );

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(curRot, goalRot, curAngleRotate);

            // Update how much we've rotated already. This determines
            // if we get to go through the while loop again.
            angleTraveledThisFrame += curAngleRotate;

            if (angleTraveledThisFrame < maxAngleRotatePerFrame ) {  
                // If we have more rotating to do this frame,
                // increment the index.
                ind++;

                if (ind==dataLen) {
                    // If you need to do anything when you run out of rotations, 
                    // you can do it here.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```